# C++ incorrect division & multiplication issue

Tags: c++

I am writing a program and I noticed that my `a` variable is not calculated correctly.
Here is the code:

```
int a = int(34 / 40 * 40);
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

When I run it, it outputs `0`. However, 34 / 40 * 40 is 34.

I suppose the issue is in division, because if I replace it with multiplication (34 / 40 = 0.85), it works just fine:

```
int a = int(0.85 * 40);
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

Output:
`34`
In my case I can just use multiplying, but what if somebody will need to divide variables?

Comment: when you divide integers the result is an integer. You want `int a = 34.0 / 40.0 * 40.0;`

Comment: `34 / 40 * 40` is only 34 in mathematics not in C++ (or many other programming languages). In C++ `34 / 40` is zero, the result of dividing two integers is always another integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you divide an integer by an integer, you will always get an integer as a result. Therefore, when an integer is divided by an integer, the reminder of the result is discarded, in your case .85 is discarded.

```
int = int / int
```

However, if one of the numerator or denominator is a floats your result will also be a float.

```
float = float / float
float = int / float
float = float / int
```

In your case:

```
float numerator = 34;
float denominator = 40;

int a = numerator / denominator * 40;
```

Pay attention that multiplication groups from left to right like pointed out by Pete Becker

Comment: I'd remove the `int( ..)` cast, because its a code smell that is not needed here. Assigning the result to `a` is sufficient to get an `int`

Comment: Minor point: if **either** the numerator **or** the denominator is a float (and the other is an int or a float) the result is a float.

Comment: This is missing an important point: division and multiplication group left to right. That is, `numerator / denominator * 40` means `(numerator / denominator) * 40` and not `numerator / (denominator * 40)`.

Comment: @PeteBecker good calls, i have edited the answer according to your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that integer arithmetic is performed with integers all the way through, at no point will any operand be changed to a floating point format unless you specifically ask for it.

As such `34 / 40 == 0` because all decimals are stripped, and then trivially `0 * 40 == 0`.

On the other hand `0.85 * 40` features operands of types `double` and `int`, and as such floating point arithmetic is used and the result is `34.0` (type `double`), which is then converted to the int `34`.

Note that a single floating point variable will cause the result to be floating point, so `34.0 / 40 * 40` will also work. BUT beware that this only applies from the point the floating point is introduced in the expression grouping (which then turns into a discussion of operator precedence, see (*) at the bottom).

So `(2 / 3) + (4.0 / 5) == 0.8` because `(2 / 3) == 0` is evaluated using integer arithmetic, then `(4.0 / 5) == 0.8` because one of the operands is floating point, and finally `0 + 0.8 == 0.8`.

If you are in doubt, then apply parenthesis to force the grouping you want. On that note `34 * (40 / 40)` also work - in both integer and floating point.

(*) How expressions are evaluated depends on [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)
and manual parenthesis grouping. So for example `34 / 40 * 40` groups as `(34 / 40) * 40` because multiplication and division are left-to-right associative and of equal precedence.

On the other hand `2 / 3 + 4.0 / 5` groups as `(2 / 3) + (4.0 / 5)` because multiplication and division have higher precedence than addition. This also means that `2 / 3 + 4.0 / 5` and `4.0 / 5 + 2 / 3` both evaluate to the same result, since in both cases the `2/3` group is evaluated using integer arithmetic before the two groups are added.

Comment: "onward" isn't really a good description of how things group: `34 / 40.0 * 40` will also work. And it's not about evaluation order; it's about **grouping**. Division and multiplication group left to right, so `a / b * c` is `(a / b) * c`. Evaluation order is about what happens when: `f() / g() * h()` groups left to right, just like the previous expression, but the order of evaluation of the three function calls is unspecified.

Comment: @PeteBecker I used evaluation order in the mathematical sense, but I can see how that could be misunderstood given that *order of evaluation* has a different meaning in programming, so I replaced it with *grouping* per your suggestion. I have also replaced "onward" with a note that should explain when integer to floating point promotion happens in a more comprehensive way.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> 0    int a = int(34 / 40 * 40);
>> 1    int a = int((34 / 40) * 40);
>> 2    int a = int(0 * 40);
>> 3    int a = int(0);
>> 4    int a = 0;
```

Please try this

```
int a = int(34.0 / 40 * 40);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    float a = 34.0 / 40.0;
    int b = a * 40;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Try this, because at division the C++ compiler make cast to integer, type used on variable. On example above the division is do with float variable.

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.